# WooCommerce subscriptions, how to get available plans based on product_id or product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I'm trying to get the available plans from a variable product in WooCommerce, based on product_id.
I can't find it in the documents or in the functions which are provided by WooCommerce Subscriptions itself.

For example this works:

```
//RETURNS THE SUBSCRIPTIONS WHICH HAS THE PRODUCT IN IT
$subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_product($product_id);
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
//WISHED THIS RETURNS THE PLANS WHICH FROM THE PRODUCT (FOR EXAMPLE)
$subscription_plans = wcs_get_product_plans($product_id);
```

I don't know how to approach the available plans, are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For representing variations of a variable product wc defines a `WC_Product_Variable` class that extends `WC_Product` class as explained [here](https://doc.hotexamples.com/class/-/WC_Product_Variable),

To get the subscription plans, considering that SubscriptionPlan extends WC_Product too, it should be as simple as:

```
$variableProduct = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
$subscription_plans = $variableProduct->get_available_variations();
```

Comment: I've forget to tell there was an extra plugin called: All Products For Woocommerce Subscriptions. The only thing I had to do was to call the meta data from the product!
    $subscription_plans = get_post_meta($product->id, '_wcsatt_schemes');
But thank's anyway!

Comment: Well this answer to the current question. Mark as accepted and create a new one updating the code with the status you currently achieved. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask